# ruby on rails ,NoMethodError in Articles#edit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
on my edit html.erb .i get the error above,and i can't create the edit file.below is my code i'm still new to ruby.

<h>Edit existing article</h>
<%@article.errors %>
<h2>The following errors prevented the article from getting created</h2>
<ul>
<%@.errors.full_messages.each do  |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li
f.text_f
 i>
<% end %>
</ul>
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
 <p>



 <%= f.label :title %><br/>
   <%=eld :title %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :description %><br/>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>
```

and the error i get is below
Showing /home/nitrous/code/rails_projects/alpha-blog/app/views/articles/edit.html.erb where line #2 raised:

    undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
    Extracted source (around line #2):

1
2
3
4
5
6

    Edit existing article

### The following errors prevented the article from getting created

- 
  below is my article_controller.rb code
      Edit existing article
  ### The following errors prevented the article from getting created
- 

Comment: Show your controller 'edit' action code. It looks like you did not populate @article.

Comment: i just added my articles_controller.rb code